# How to fix error when using OpenCV in Clion

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, clion

I'm trying to use OpenCV in Clion and I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjq8eTuHnMM&ab_channel=EthernelTech). I installed opencv with `choco install opencv`

But after running the program I get this error:

```
D:\Apps\CLion 2022.3.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_core
D:\Apps\CLion 2022.3.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
D:\Apps\CLion 2022.3.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
D:\Apps\CLion 2022.3.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(GTSpeed)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(ENV{OPENCV_DIR} "C:\\tools\\opencv\\build")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(GTSpeed main.cpp gtspeed/Keyboard.cpp gtspeed/Keyboard.h gtspeed/Logger.cpp gtspeed/Logger.h gtspeed/Config.cpp gtspeed/Config.h)
#add_executable(GTSpeed main.cpp)

set(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)
target_link_libraries(GTSpeed ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

My system environment variables:

[image: System variables]

And this is my user variable for path:

```
C:\tools\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin
```

I searched this online but there weren't answers for Clion and opencv in c++.

Also before I got this error it had another issue but I solved it.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/tools/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.
```

So I went in the file and changed set(OpenCV_FOUND FALSE) to TRUE. I don't know if this affected anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to me that you are building using `mingw` however your
`C:\tools\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin` seems to be pointing to libraries built using MSVC. As is seen from the `vc15`.

You either need to build OpenCV libraries using `mingw` or you need to use `MSVC` for your project.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: I did not notice your EDIT... that is definitely a bad idea. OpenCV_FOUND is set by CMake (specifically the FindCMake.cmake or similar config files). DO NOT set this manually yourself.

EDIT2: Here is a link on [how to configure CLion so that it uses MSVC](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#MSVC)

Comment: I changed it in settings but then this comes up: `ninja: error: build.ninja:35: loading 'CMakeFiles/rules.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Have you installed Visual Studio dev tools through the VS Installer as the guide in EDIT2 suggests?

Comment: I think I have it. It says on https://imgur.com/a/JBE6N9K

Comment: Try cleaning the CMake cache and regenerate the build files using CMake. I am not as familiar with CLion as I am with Visual Studio, but you should have such an option in the toolbar (perhaps under build). Something on the lines of `Clean build` or `Clean CMake cache` -> the reasoning behind this is because you've most likely generated the CMake files using the mingw settings.